# python data type comparisons

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)

Can any one explain the below.how is the 'a' compared to 1
Internally is a and 1 ASCII  val is compared or how is it
i.e, there is some conversion happening with 'a' and then compared or how is this.Please explain

```
>>> 'a' > 1
True
>>> 'a' > 'b'
False
```

Comment: seems like a duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different types are compared lexigraphically, and "int" is < "string".

In python 3.x, it changes this so different types aren't comparible.

Bool < Int:

```
In [15]: True > 5
Out[15]: False
```

List > Int:

```
In [14]: [1, 2] > 5
Out[14]: True
```

Tuple > List:

```
In [16]: (1, 2) > [1, 2]
Out[16]: True
```

And for your example:
Str > Int:

```
In [17]: '1' > 5
Out[17]: True
```

And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

from the manual :

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except
>   numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types
>   that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

so "str" is greater then "int"